# Email enter field in FirebaseUI is not visible when not activated, even though I have colour controls in styles

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have recently updated the Firebase versions in my project to recent versions:

> ```
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.4.5"
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.1"
> "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2"
> "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0"
> ```

After updating, I am getting a UI issue in Firebase AuthUI. The email enter field, when not activated, is not visible, as shown in the screenshot, even though I have colour controls in styles. It's visible only when I tap on it to activate it.

I am using below style :

```
<style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Code:

```
   // Choose authentication providers
        val providers = arrayListOf(
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        )

        // Create and launch sign-in intent
        val signInIntent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.handshake) // Set logo drawable               
            .build()
        signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
```

**When not activated**

[image: When not activated]

**When activated**

[image: When activated]